# How to change the views of Price-list Item Entity in Microsoft Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I want to change the views of Price-list item entity in Dynamics CRM.

By default, Dynamics CRM doesn't allow us to change any view of price-list item entity, but still, I want to change those view.

So, Is there any workaround or a way to change the views.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the XML: download the entity in a solution, and open in a text editor the `customizations.xml` file.

You'll be able to track down the FetchXML for the view inside the file (it's likely quite a big one) and change it. As always when dealing with FetchXML, the Advanced Find is your friend to almost-effortlessly achieve valid XML to put there.

After that, repack the solution and import it, the view vill be overwritten.

In case you're wondering, this is a *supported* customization.

Comment: An afterthought: this method of customizing views always works on paper, but I can't recall if I tried to do exactly this in the past. As usual, keep backups, try it out, see what happens

Comment: I had tried the same way before but after changing the customization in this way and after importing the solution it's not getting affected.